# Does random_state in train_test_split effect the actual performance of a model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression, train-test-split

I get why a model's score is different for each random_state but did expect the difference between the highest and the lowest score (from random_state 0-100) to be 0.37 which is lot. Also tried ten-fold-cross-validation, the difference is still kinda big.

So does this actually matter or is it something i should ignore ?

[The Data-set link](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Student+Performance)
(Download -> Data Folder -> student.zip -> student-mat.csv)

Full Code :

```
import pandas as pd

acc_dic = {}
grade_df_main = pd.read_csv(r'F:\Python\Jupyter Notebook\ML Projects\data\student-math-grade.csv', sep = ";")
grade_df = grade_df_main[["G1", "G2", "G3", "studytime", "failures", "absences"]]

X = grade_df.drop("G3", axis = "columns")
Y = grade_df["G3"].copy()

def cross_val_scores(scores):
    print("Cross validation result :-")
    #print("Scores: {}".format(scores))
    print("Mean: {}".format(scores.mean()))
    print("Standard deviation: {}".format(scores.std()))

def start(rand_state):

    print("Index {}".format(rand_state))

    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
    x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=.1, random_state=rand_state)

    from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
    lin_reg_obj = LinearRegression()
    lin_reg_obj.fit(x_train, y_train)

    accuracy = lin_reg_obj.score(x_test, y_test)
    print("Accuracy: {}".format(accuracy))
    acc_dic[rand_state] = accuracy

    from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
    scores = cross_val_score(lin_reg_obj, x_test, y_test, scoring="neg_mean_squared_error", cv=10)

    cross_val_scores(scores)
    print()


for i in range(0, 101):
    start(i)

print("Overview : \n")
result_val = list(acc_dic.values())

min_index = result_val.index(min(result_val))
max_index = result_val.index(max(result_val))

print("Minimum Accuracy : ")
start(min_index)

print("Maximum Accuracy : ")
start(max_index)
```

Result :

```
Only included the highest and the lowest results

Minimum Accuracy : 
Index 54
Accuracy: 0.5635271419142645
Cross validation result :-
Mean: -8.969894370977539
Standard deviation: 5.614516642510817

Maximum Accuracy : 
Index 97
Accuracy: 0.9426035720345269
Cross validation result :-
Mean: -0.7063598117158191
Standard deviation: 0.3149445166291036
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**

It is not the split on the dataset you used to train and evaluate your model that decides how well your final model will actually perform once it is deployed. The split and evaluation technique is more about getting a valid estimation of how well the model might perform in real life. And as you can see, the choice of the splitting and evaluation technique can have a great influence on this estimation. The results on your dataset highly suggest preferring k-fold cross-validation over a simple train/test split.

---

**Longer version**

I believe you have already figured out that the split you do on the dataset to separate it into train and test sets has nothing to do with the performance of your final model, which is likely to be trained on the whole dataset and then be deployed.

The purpose of testing is to get a feeling of the predictive performance on unseen data. In a best-case scenario, you would ideally have two completely different data sets from different cohorts/sources to train and test your model (*external validation*). This is the best approach to evaluate how your model would perform once it is deployed. However, since you often do not have such a second source of data, you do an *internal validation* where you get samples for training and testing from the same cohort/source.

Usually, given that this dataset is big enough, randomness will make sure that the splits for the train and test sets are a good representation of your original dataset and the performance metrics you get are a fair estimation of the model's predictive performance in real life.

However, as you see on your own dataset, there are cases where the split does actually heavily influence the result. It is exactly for such cases, where you are definitely better off evaluating your performance with a cross-validation technique such as k-fold cross-validation, and compute the mean across different splits.

Comment: I partially disagree with you. Yes, splitting the dataset differently affects the results since every time you get different in-the-sample and out-the-sample which may or may not represent the actual statistical distribution of the population. Just imagine that out-the-sample mostly contains novelties. However, I do agree on the Cross-Validation which basically overcomes having different results when changing the random state but actually having an averaged score over the "different splits"!